# ERROR: operator does not exist: bigint = bigint[]

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL Query

```
SELECT type from types where id in (SELECT type_ids from user where id=1)
```

Here the subquery

```
SELECT type_ids from user where id=1
```

returns the value of type bigint[].
How can i resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` if I understand correctly:

```
select t.type
from types t
where exists (select 1
              from user u
              where u.id = 1 and
                    t.id = any (u.type_ids)
             );
```

Or, more simply, a `join` should do what you want:

```
select t.type
from types t join
     users u
     on t.id = any(u.type_ids)
where u.id = 1;
```

Although this can return duplicates if `type_ids` has duplicates.

Comment: I think the `= ANY` is the key here, rather than the `exists` or the `join`; the sub-query likely returns a single row.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference between a *list* of values, and an *array value*, and [the operations you can use for each](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html).

The `IN` operator compares a value against a *list* of values, such as a sub-query that returns several rows. So it would be appropriate for something like `SELECT type from types where id in (SELECT type_id from user)` is `type_id` was a single `bigint`, but the sub-query returned several rows.

As the documentation says, `id in (a, b, c)` is equivalent to `id=a OR id=b OR id=c`, which is why you're getting an error: Postgres tries to compute `id = (SELECT type_ids from user where id=1)` but doesn't know how to compare a `bigint` against an array of bigints (`bigint[]`).

The `= ANY` operator instead compares a value against a *single array value*, which is what you have here: `SELECT type_ids from user where id=1` returns a single row, but the value in that row is an array (a `bigint[]` value).

So one way to write the query is:

```
SELECT type from types where id = ANY (SELECT type_ids from user where id=1)
```

Comment: I tried using it but still, it gives me the same error.